# Unable to go back through a navigation controller to a VC of another navigation controller using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, popviewcontroller

As you can see below, the `notificationsVC` is a part of the **TabBarController** which is embedded in a `navigationContoller`(lets call it first nC). Then theres a segue from notificationsVC to the second navigationController which will show the messagesVC.

There's a back button in `messagesVC` which when pressed should go back to `notificationsVC`

```
func backbutton() {        
    navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)         
}
```

Now this is obviously not working because the navigationController will get the nearest NC and pop the VC in its stack but it won't let me go back to the `notificationsVC`.

Any other alternative?, although I've tried this with no success as well.

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
```

[image]

More detailed view
[image]

Also I'm using the [JSQMessagesViewController](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController) library to show the messages in `messagesVC` which shouldn't matter but still worth mentioning. Thanks for your time!

Comment: `navigationController?.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)` Pop view from NavigationController of NavigationController.

Answer (score 0):

Try : -

```
let nVC = self.navigationController?.tabBarController?.navigationController?.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NotificationStoryboardVC_ID") as! NotificationVC

navigationController?.tabBarController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(nVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: NotificationStoryboardVC_ID is the same thing as the one we set in attribute inspector right? Also pushViewController won't take in a string.

Comment: My bad...;), i have edited the answer, but i guess you tried this already?

Answer (score 0):

You can access first NavigationViewController by asking it from TabBarViewController like in code below:

```
tabBarController?.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Also asking navigation controller from you second navigation controller should work:

```
navigationController?.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Navigation controller has only one VC i.e MessagesVc. So when you pop it,there is no other VC in the Navigation Controller's stack which can be presented. Your NotificationsVC is not in the Navigation controller's stack.

So I suggest you to do like this on back button click:

**tabBarController?.selectedIndex = Index_Of_NotificationsVC**